# How to search for applications in Unity?

Tags: 10.10, unity

So far when I want to run an application, I click the Ubuntu button (or whatever it's called in the upper left), then Games, then All Applications, then I can either select or search for an application.  Is that really the best way?  The "Games" part really throws me :)

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: The part just before the question mark

Comment: I assume this is with 10.10 Netbook Edition?

Comment: @fluteflute, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unity, you should be able to:

- click on the Apps Place (an icon on the launcher which says "Applications")
- enter the name of the app in the search field

... and you should see your app listed there, either as installed or available.

You can also use the Ubuntu button, but then you are searching both applications AND files.

Answer (score 0):

Hi your asking about searching for applications in unity.But in your question say that click ubuntu and etc etc. Are sure about unity ?. As far as i know Unity is available only in ubuntu Net book edition and ubuntu Natty desktop and its variants.Because if use unity you will see an interface as shown in this link http://www.ubuntu.com/netbook/features. You can add the search menu item in the Unity bar.So, you can easily access search on one click.